# CameraPreview Ionic Cordova error 'plugin_not_installed', but the plugin IS installed | Angular 8

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm making an application who needs to get photos and sending this last on server.
So, the application is made with Ionic 5 & Angular 8.

I've installed this plugin [CameraPreview](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/camera-preview) and this is my PhotoComponent:

```
      constructor(
    private cameraPreview: CameraPreview
    ) { }

  takePhoto() {
    // camera options (Size and location). In the following example, the preview uses the rear camera and display the preview in the back of the webview
    const cameraPreviewOpts: CameraPreviewOptions = {
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      width: window.screen.width,
      height: window.screen.height,
      camera: 'rear',
      tapPhoto: true,
      previewDrag: true,
      toBack: true,
      alpha: 1
    }

    // start camera
    this.cameraPreview.startCamera(cameraPreviewOpts).then(
      (res) => {
        console.log(res)
      },
      (err) => {
        console.log(err)
      });
    }

}
```

So, this it my HTML component

```
...
<button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="takePhoto()">prendi la foto</button>
...
```

i've installed the camera-preview plugin like this:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera-preview
npm install @ionic-native/camera-preview
```

running `cordova plugin list` i see this:

```
cordova-plugin-camera-preview 0.11.2 "cordova-plugin-camera-preview"
```

This is my Provides on app module:

```
providers: [
    CameraPreview
    ]
```

BUT, when i run `ionic cordova run android` and i run the method takePhoto()

i got this error: 
[image]

i've alredy tried to uninstall, remove android platform but nothing..the error doesn't go away

**UPDATE**
i've added check on platform but Chrome canary print me:

```
Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
cordova.js:1233 deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds.
cordova.js:1226 Channel not fired: onCordovaInfoReady
```

maybe the problem is this ?

Any solutions ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That issue happens often because the platform is not ready yet. Please consider checking the platform is ready before you call any of your plugins:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
import { CameraPreview, CameraPreviewOptions } from '@ionic-native/camera-preview/ngx'; // don't add ngx if you are on 'ionic-angular' mode

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private platform: Platform,
    private cameraPreview: CameraPreview
  ) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.platform.ready().then(_ => {
      this.takePhoto() // here the call of your function
    })
  }

  takePhoto() {
    const cameraPreviewOpts: CameraPreviewOptions = {
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      width: window.screen.width,
      height: window.screen.height,
      camera: 'rear',
      tapPhoto: true,
      previewDrag: true,
      toBack: true,
      alpha: 1
    }

    // start camera
    this.cameraPreview.startCamera(cameraPreviewOpts).then(
      (res) => {
        console.log(res)
      },
      (err) => {
        console.log(err)
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response. I've tried and now chrome canary print me the message i've put in the update section in the question.

Comment: @Mr.Developer these 3 lines are info and shouldn't stop the app functionality from working, you can neglect them for now. Is the plugin working after then ?

Comment: sorry but the plugin did not work after force. I'm still searching other solutions. Thanks